# How to define multiple properties for a single component in react

Tags: reactjs

I have declared a component as below 
**Main.js** 
`<Hello data={"foo"} DateTime={new Date()}/>` 
**Index.jsx**  
I have coded render function as below 
render(){
        return (`<div>` 
            `<h1>` Hello, {this.props.data}`</h1>`
            `<p>` Now time is {this.props.DateTime}`</p>`
        `</div>`);
    }
It gives me error. Please let me know what mistake am i doing here.

Comment: please create a plunker demonstrating your issue...thx

Comment: And what is the error message?

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/byf8VWj0VBASnKMOSdSo?p=info

Comment: error message goes here

Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: Sun Feb 11 2018 21:03:46 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

Answer (score 0):

Read the error message. It should be "Objects are not valid as a React child".

use `this.props.DateTime.toString()` (or any other way to covert date object into a string) instead of just `this.props.DateTime`.

Comment: Thanks Yurii.. This fixed the issue